# How to view Tomcat logs in PCFDev?

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I'm deploying a 2.3.5 Grails application with mysql in PCFDev. Hitting some URLs in my application I get a 500 error. When I view the logs with `cf logs my-sample` I only see access logs. They don't show my stacktrace.

How can I actually see the stacktrace in the logs so that I know exactly what is causing the error? Usually when deploying the app in Tomcat, I would see these logs in `/logs` directory of Tomcat.

This is what my `config.groovy` looks like for my grails application.

```
def catalinaBase = System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base')
if (!catalinaBase) catalinaBase = '.'   // just in case
def logDirectory = "${catalinaBase}/logs"
        log4j = { root ->
            appenders {
//                console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n")
                rollingFile name:'stdout', file:"${logDirectory}/my.log".toString(), maxFileSize:'100KB'
                rollingFile name:'stacktrace', file:"${logDirectory}/my_stack.log".toString(), maxFileSize:'100KB'
            }
            warn    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
                    'org.springframework',
                    'org.hibernate'
            debug   'com.aerstone.ldap', 'com.aerstone.scanner.helper'
            root.level = org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling "cf logs" brings up http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html as the first result.  It has a section on ["Writing to the Log from Your App"](http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#writing).  It says:

> Your app must write logs to `STDERR` or `STDOUT`. Both are typically buffered, and you should flush the buffer before delivering the message to Loggregator.

In addition to writing to a directory or file, you should consider also sending that output to `STDOUT` and `STDERR` streams as per the [Twelve-Factor App treatment of logs](https://12factor.net/logs).

Also, you can search "cf ssh" which gives [this result](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html) explaining how you can SSH into your apps' containers and look at things on their local file system.

Comment: Does CF provide a sample of a recommended log4j setting for a grails or spring boot app?

Comment: That I'm not sure of, unfortunately.

Comment: You're almost there.  You have the console appender commented out in your example above.  Uncomment that and comment out the rolling file appenders.  That should cause your app to log to STDOUT, which will be visible when you run `cf logs`.